# Get calling method information via custom implementation of @PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop

Hi we are implementing ABAC over SpringSecurity (looks same as Axiomatics solution). So we would like to define custome expression and customize underlaying mechanisms. e.g. @PreAuthorize("myexpression").

At this point I'm trying understand how can I get information about the target method (the JoinPoint): name, class, parameters. I didn't find how to do it for SpringSecurity customization.

As I Inderstand, other solution may be implemention based direct on AOP e.g. @Around, however I would like to try first to find out if the Spring Security can provide me a way to get somehow JoinPoint it self, isn't it implemented over AOP ?

If anyone have an example, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [Pre and Post Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html#el-pre-post-annotations) in the docs, which includes these details. What expression are you trying to use? How are you trying to customize? You can use any SpEL expression including an @bean invocation without customization.

Comment: I would like to get information about calling method, I can't get this information e.g. name, class, parameters using @bean invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking out the new support for `@PreAuthorize` in Spring Security 5.6 with `@EnableMethodSecurity`. See the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.0-M1/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#jc-method-security-custom-authorization-manager) for information on how to customize the interceptors. There are numerous places you can hook into this support based on your requirements using delegation or fully replacing components with your own implementation.

In your case, it seems the most likely place to start would be creating an `@Bean` to replace the `AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor`:

```java
    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    Advisor preAuthorizeAuthorizationMethodInterceptor() {
        PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager authorizationManager = new PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager();
        authorizationManager.setExpressionHandler(...);
        return AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.preAuthorize(authorizationManager);
    }
```

You will have to implement the `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, but you can use delegation to re-use the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` for anything you don't want to implement yourself.

Comment: Thanks, we are looking into new features of Spring Security 5.6. Is there any examples for 5.6 fetures ?

Comment: The reference docs cover the new `@EnableMethodSecurity` well. The other major new feature is `JwtEncoder`, which the [JWT Login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) sample demonstrates. For everything else, you can check out [What's New](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/whats-new.html) and the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases) for each version (including milestones/release candidates).